# Model OpenAPI 2.0 file download, type string:binary vs. type file

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I'm a little confused how to model a file download with Swagger/OpenAPI v2. Take this small example:

```yaml
/files/{name}.zip:
  get:
    summary: Returns the requested ZIP file as "file download" i.e. with content-disposition = attachment
    produces:
      - application/zip
    parameters:
      - name: name
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
    responses:
      200:
        description: OK
        schema:
          type: file      # <- what is it?
        headers:
          Content-Disposition:
            type: string
            description: the value is `attachment; filename="name.zip"`
```

What do I use as response type? Is it `type: string` & `format: binary` or simply `type: file`?

I was looking at https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#data-types and  https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#response-object (response data type `file`) but it isn't clear to me how the two are different. Which should be used when?

Also, does the use of the `Content-Disposition` header make a difference for choosing one or the other?

Note to self, also looked at

- https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/430
- https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/50
- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/319#issuecomment-113880278

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a private conversation with the OpenAPI folks on gitter.im I was told the following.

> In OAS v3, `file` has been replaced by `type: string, format: binary` instead
>   so if you're planning to upgrade your spec to OAS v3 eventually, i would suggest you use binary from now on

Answer (score 3):

The `type: file` [was removed in version 3.0.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.0.md#considerations-for-file-uploads) of the spec and should be replaced with something like

```yaml
   schema:
     type: string
     format: binary
```

In version 3.1.0 it looks like this is the [default behavior for content transferred in binary](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.1.0.md#considerations-for-file-uploads), so the above may even be omitted.